# Azure Queue change size after creating

Tags: azure-queues

I have a production Azure Queue created with the 1GB limit.  Now I want to change this to 5GB.  Is it possible to change this without deleting and recreating the queue?

Comment: Is this a Service Bus Queue or Azure table queue?

Comment: Service Bus Queue.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage Queues are not of any particular size. Just to be sure - Are you talking about the following? If not please change the tag to Service Bus or something more relevant so that you get the right attention.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/